# React - Axios to get props return always promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I have a react application that renders from a main component, when this component is mounted I fetch some data using redux thunk and pass the response as a global state, in this main component there is a component that render a specific item of the array of data that redux passed as props, for this I filter the array data with the id parameter in the url that match, the problem is that when the page is reloaded this data is no longer available so the view of the specific item crash, so I am trying to create a ternary operator condition that check if the props array length is 0 then an axios request is done to the api to get the specific item using the parameter of the url but though I see the response in the console this does not pass as prop to the component that render the specific item just the promise is seen.

the main component is this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Routes, Route, Navigate, useParams, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'; //Switch changed to routes Also redirect is changed to Navigate since version 6
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';


import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Home from './home-components/HomeComponent';

import Footer from './FooterComponent';

import Vitrina from './vitrina-components/VitrinaComponent';
import CarDetailComponent from './vitrina-components/CardetailComponent';
import {fetchCars, fetchOfertas} from '../redux/ActionCreators';
import axios from 'axios';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

// --------Hook to use withRouter from v5 in actual v6-----------------
export const withRouter = (Component) => {
  const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const history = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const params = useParams();
    
    return (
      <Component
        history={history}
        location={location}
        params={params}
        {...props}
        />
    );
  };
  
  return Wrapper;
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{

        cars: state.cars
       
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  //axios fetch data function
  fetchCars: () => { dispatch(fetchCars())}

});



class Main extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    //when mounted the data is fetched
    this.props.fetchCars(); 
  }
  
  render(){
  
    //this is the component where the specific item is rendered    
    const CarWithId = () => {

      let params = useParams();
      
      return(
          // here is the actual logic to pass the specific item to the component to render
          <CarDetailComponent car={this.props.cars.cars.filter((car) => car._id === params.carId)[0]}/>
        
      );
    };
    
  return (  
    
    <div>
      <Header/>  
      <Routes>
        <Route path = "/login" element = {<LoginComponent/>}/>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home cars={this.props.cars}/>}/> 

        <Route exact path="/vitrina" element= {<Vitrina cars={this.props.cars} />} />  
        <Route path = "/vitrina/:carId" element={<CarWithId />} />

        <Route path="*"element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
        {/* Instead of redirect the above is needed to redirect if there is no matched url*/}
      </Routes>
      
      <Footer location={this.props.location}/>
    </div>
  );
}
};



export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

what I am trying right now in the CarWithId to pass the specific item when the page is reloaded is this

```
    const CarWithId = () => {
      let params = useParams();

      async function getCar(){
        let car;
        await axios.get(baseUrl+'cars/'+params.carId)
        .then((response) => {
            car = response.data
            console.log('response.data',response.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
        return car;
      }
      
      return(

          <CarDetailComponent car={this.props.cars.cars.length===0 ?  getCar() :this.props.cars.cars.filter((car) => car._id === params.carId)[0]}/>
        
      );
    };
```

but i get this in the console when login the getCar() function

[image: response with getCar()]

how can i correctly do the axios request in order to pass the response.data as the car to the carDetailComponent, also in the inner `console.log('response.data',response.data)` of the function the response is as what i expect but for a reason in the car this is not passed as the prop

**EDIT added the carDetailComponent**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
        //Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle,
         Breadcrumb,BreadcrumbItem} from 'reactstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import { baseUrl } from '../../shared/baseUrl';
import { formatMoney } from '../../shared/utils';
import whatsappIcon from '../../static/assets/icons/whatsapp.svg';


const imgPath = baseUrl + "images/vehiculos/";
function RenderCar({car}){

  // hooks to manage the state of the component
  
  if (car != null){
      const message = `Hola, estoy interesado en el vehículo ${car.marca} ${car.linea} ${car.modelo}`;
     
    return(
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row mb-2">
            
            {/* < -- Col -- > */}
            <div className="col-12 col-md-9">
              <div className='container-fluid '>
                <div className='row'>

                  {/* < -- Col -- > */}
                  <div className='col-2'>
                    {/* here will be showed the miniatures in vertical when one is clicked will have a blue border*/}
                    {car.images.map((image, index) => {
                      return(
                        <div key={index} className='row vertical-center'>
                          {/* images must be responsive */}
                          <img src={imgPath +
                            car.marca + "_" + car.linea + "_" + car.modelo + "/" + image}
                            alt={car.marca + "_" + car.linea + "_" + car.modelo + "_" + index}
                            className= {`card side-column-images px-0 mb-2 ${currentImage === index ? "selected" : undefined}`} 
                            onClick={() => setCurrentImage(index)}
                            onMouseOver={() => setCurrentImage(index)}
                          />

                        </div>
                      );
                    })}


                  </div>

                  {/* < -- Col -- > */}
                  <div className='col-10'>
                    
                    <img 
                      className="card-img-top principal-image-vitrina mx-2" 
                      src={imgPath + car.marca + "_" + car.linea + "_" + car.modelo + "/" + car.images[currentImage]} 
                      alt={car.name}
                    />
             

                   
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* < -- Col -- > */}           
             {/*car information  Marca, linea, modelo, precio*/}
            <div className="col-3 col-md-3 card pb-2">
              <div className="card-body">
                <p className="card-text text-muted responsive-text">{car.modelo} | {car.km} km</p>
                <h3 className="card-title responsive-title">{car.marca} {car.linea}</h3>
                
                
                <h2 className="card-text display-6">${formatMoney(car.price)}</h2>

                {/* buttons for buy and other to contact via whatsapp */}
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Comprar</button>
                  </div>
                  {/* use whatsapp.svg icon that is on static/assets/icons*/}
                  <div className="col-12 col-md-6">
                    {/* button will redirect to wppApi onClick*/}
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn-block" onClick={() => window.open(wppApi, "_blank")}>
                      <img src={whatsappIcon} alt="whatsapp" style={{height:20, width:20,fill:"white"}} className="whatsapp-icon"/>
                      Contactar
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          {/* principal characterist rendered in a table, modelo, marca, linea, Tipo, km, cilindrake,transmision,direccion,combustible,color*/}
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-md-9">
              <div className="">
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h4 className="card-title">Caracteristicas Principales</h4>
                  <table className="table table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Modelo</th>
                        <td>{car.modelo}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Marca</th>
                        <td>{car.marca}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Linea</th>
                        <td>{car.linea}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Tipo</th>
                        <td>{car.Tipo}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Kilometraje</th>
                        <td>{car.km}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Cilindraje</th>
                        <td>{car.cilindraje}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Transmision</th>
                        <td>{car.transmision}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Direccion</th>
                        <td>{car.direccion}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Combustible</th>
                        <td>{car.combustible}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>  
                        <th scope="row">Color</th>
                        <td>{car.color}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
  else{
    return(
      // redirects user to /vitrina route
      <div>
        <h3>No se encontro el carro</h3>
      </div>


      );
        }
}


const CarDetailComponents = (props)=> {
    
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <Breadcrumb>
                <BreadcrumbItem><Link to="/vitrina">vitrina</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
                <BreadcrumbItem active>{props.car.marca} {props.car.linea}</BreadcrumbItem>
            </Breadcrumb>
            <div className="col-12">
                <h3>{props.car.marca} {props.car.linea}</h3>
                <hr/>
            </div>                
          </div>

          <div className="row">     
            <RenderCar car={props.car}/>               
          </div>
        </div>
      );

}


export default CarDetailComponents;
```

Comment: `getCar()` is just an asynchronous function, and you are not awaiting it, so when you call it, it returns a promise yet to be resolved

Comment: but i set await inside the function before the axios get, or how is the correct way to await this?

Comment: yes, when you call `getCar` you also need to await it. Where are you setting the response from the `getCar` function to redux?

Comment: if i write await before the getCar() i get the error ```'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts(1308)``` also this is not using redux, redux is used when the view is not reloaded, i am trying to call the getCar() when the page is reloaded in order to get the specific car from the api with the getCar(), my logic render all from mainComponent so if i'm inside another component and reload the page the main component is mounted and the data won't be fetched again, that's why I'm trying to get the car prop to the carDetailComponent with axios

Comment: so in the ternary operator i check if the this.props.cars.cars data brought by redux is empty then the getCar() will get the car prop if is not empty then the data of redux is passed as prop

Comment: can you post the `CarDetailComponent`code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250441/discussion-between-unhackit-and-ttt2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `getCar` function from your `CarWithId` component
2. You can leave the render of the car details component like this

```
<CarDetailComponent car={this.props.cars.cars.length===0 ? null :this.props.cars.cars.filter((car) => car._id === params.carId)[0]}/>
```

3. Then update your CarDetailComponents to this

```
const CarDetailComponents = (props)=> {
    const [car, setCar] = useState(props.car)
    let params = useParams();

    async function getCar(){
      await axios.get(baseUrl+'cars/'+params.carId)
      .then((response) => {         
          setCar(response.data)
          console.log('response.data',response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
      })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!props.car){
            getCar()
        }
    },[props.car])


    
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <Breadcrumb>
              <BreadcrumbItem><Link to="/vitrina">vitrina</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
              <BreadcrumbItem active>{car?.marca} {car?.linea}</BreadcrumbItem>
          </Breadcrumb>
          <div className="col-12">
              <h3>{car?.marca} {car?.linea}</h3>
              <hr/>
          </div>                
        </div>

        <div className="row">    
        {car &&  <RenderCar car={car}/>   } 
              
        </div>
      </div>
    );

}
```

This will check if car is assigned, if not it will fetch the car

Comment: thanks you a lot, it worked but could you please explain me what does the ```{car?.marca}``` do? what does the ? means why is not needed to use ```props.car.marca```

Comment: if you use `car.marca` and car is null, it will throw an error. So the `?` will tell javascript that `car` may be undefined, and it will not throw an error. It's called`optional chaining`

Comment: srry i missclicked, thanks

Comment: also could you please explain me the ? use on the ```{car?,marca}``` please

Comment: if you use `car.marca` and `car` is null, it will throw an error. So the `?` will tell javascript that `car` may be undefined, and it will not throw an error. It's called `optional chaining`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: thanks you a lot was a really helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

why you also using await and then

how about ?

```
async function getCar() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(baseUrl + 'cars/' + params.carId);
        console.log("response.data", response.data)
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const car = await getCar()
        setCar(car)
    })();
}, [])
```

```
<CarDetailComponent car={car} />
```

Comment: thanks you a lot but the mainComponent is a class component so i cant use the useEffect hook there

Comment: @TTT2 it looks like you are using hooks all over, why not also use the useState? it doesn't matter if the parent of RenderCar component is a class component, you should be able to use useState as well inside RenderCar Component since its functional component